# Connecting to MSSQL 2008 R2 with QGIS 2.0.1

Tags: arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, qgis-2

There have been questions related to this, but some of them seem out of date or no one has asked.  I'm trying to connect to SQL Server 2008R2 using a MSSQL connection in QGIS.  I'm not exactly sure if I'm connecting to the correct site.  I'm able to connect through Autocad Civil 2014 so i'm using what I used to connect to that.  Any ideas?  The last posts I've seen are around 2011.

[image]

[image]

Comment: One does not connect *to* ArcSDE, one connects to a database *through* ArcSDE, which makes for a mismatch between title and question content.

Comment: My experience with QGIS and SDE is via PostgreSQL/PostGIS. QGIS ignored SDE altogether and connected directly to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Have you put {server_name}{instance_name} in the [Host] field? In my SQL Server instance where I have [mixed mode authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx), connecting as below works fine:

[image]